# Link a CSS file with version number for cache busting

Tags: html, css, caching, versioning

css-file is named: `style.css?v=1`

the link inside of html: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=1">`

---

Contrary to the classic `style.css` the `style.css?v=1` doesn't get recognised:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Did I miss something? What's important to versioning files and where does the syntax `?v=1` come from?

Comment: _"the `style.css?=v1` doesn't get recognised."_ Which one are you using `style.css?=v1` or `style.css?v=1` (as per your link) (correct syntax is `?v=1` and it is called a query string)

Comment: Oh thanks, there was a typo – I'm using `?v=1`

Answer (score 2):

- The expression style.css?v=1 for the browser means a dynamic file like "fetch me the file style.css with a parameter named "v" set to 1". As long as you change the value of the v parameter, the file will be fetched as a new unique url.
- The expression style.css?=v1 has no meaning.
- The expression style.css?1 could also work.

Comment: is the _query string_ only based on naming? Or is there any technical difference between `style.css?v=1` and `style-v1.css`?

Comment: The difference between these two is that if you are working on a file style.css and you want to decache it then the ?v={version_number} at the end is enough. The file style-v1.css is different than the file style-v2.css inside your server meaning that you must create a new file each time each time you want to decache it on your browser.