# Why doesn't my react application clear the cache after each deployment?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When I deploy my react application, which has a node backend, it does not update the css and front application files. I have to clear the browser cache for it to work properly.

I added the following code to de index.html but It doesn't work:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 2019 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Can I do something that works at the application level?
Do I need to do something at the web server level like Apache?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53430086/4854768 Try it, add higher number of version after js/css links. Something like www.test.com/styles.css?v=2

Comment: you can do every of `http-equiv` on web server side - thats how its done by default; right now you are specyfing this only for .html, right?

Comment: @Rhonin ok, but html not yet updated

Comment: @fard Yes, I am specyfing this only for .html but it doesn't works